# tanstack react query mutate onSettled to access PUT body data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Dears,

Due to some reason, I need access to the `PUT` request body after the `PUT` request settled.

Please check the [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/usequery-forked-t3ivfl?file=/src/App.js) I tried to prepare.

My question is - is it ok to return the `PUT` params in `onMutate` and then do some logic in `onSettled` based on these params, for example selectively setting a loading state to false.

And then, why the `PUT` params are the 3rd argument of the `onSettled` function?

p.s. please don't argue about state management, the question is about `onSettled` usage :)

Best regards,
MJ

```js
import React from "react";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";

const someProps = { prop1: "key1" };

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const { mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (someProps) =>
      await fetch("https://httpbin.org/put", {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(someProps)
      }).then((response) => response.json()),
    onSuccess: (responseData) => {
      console.log("RESPONSE ON SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(responseData));
    },
    onMutate: (data) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      console.log(
        "Yes, I have access to props before I send the request: " +
          JSON.stringify(data)
      );
      // I return the data so I can use it in on settled
      return data;
    },
    onSettled: (arg1NotUsed, arg2NotUsed, data) => {
      console.log(
        "Yes, I have access to props after I receive the response: " +
          JSON.stringify(data)
      );
      if (data) {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>is loading: {isLoading ? "LOADING" : "IDLE"}</p>
      <button onClick={() => mutate(someProps)}>trigger mutation</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variables` are available in `onSettled` even if you don't return them from `onMutate`. What `onSettled` receives is:

`onSettled(data, error, variables, context)`

where `context` is what you return from `onSettled`. In your example, you're using the 3rd parameter, which is *not* the value returned from `onMutate`, so  you can safely leave that out.

There is also no need to separately track an `isLoading` boolean, because `useMutation` does this for you and also returns a loading state.

```
export default function App() {
  const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (someProps) =>
      await fetch("https://httpbin.org/put", {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(someProps)
      }).then((response) => response.json()),
    onSuccess: (responseData) => {
      console.log("RESPONSE ON SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(responseData));
    },
    onSettled: (arg1NotUsed, arg2NotUsed, data) => {
      console.log(
        "Yes, I have access to props after I receive the response: " +
          JSON.stringify(data)
      );
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>is loading: {isLoading ? "LOADING" : "IDLE"}</p>
      <button onClick={() => mutate(someProps)}>trigger mutation</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a fork of your sandbox with these changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/usequery-forked-vq8kcr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I got confused that I have to return something because of the official docs for onMutate which say whatever you return will be passed to onError and onSettled
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useMutation

Regarding your second comment about the isLoading - yes, I know I can get it as a state from react query, but sometimes I need it as an event, like onSettled etc.

Comment: yes the docs say: "The value returned from this function will be passed to both the onError and onSettled functions in the event of a mutation failure and can be useful for rolling back optimistic updates." Maybe we should clarify that this is the `context` available in the other callbacks ... variables are passed regardless